# FastAPI testing No ORM Databases

Tags: python, postgresql, pytest, fastapi

I am a None ORM user, I prefer to use plain text queries, I took that course on free code camp on FastAPI but almost the whole course revolves around ORMs so I struggle to implement a number of concepts found in that course.

My main struggle is when I write tests for my endpoints I need to use a test database rather than my development database, I am using [testing.postgres](https://github.com/tk0miya/testing.postgresql) to create the testing database and this is the code I am using :

```py
client = TestClient(app)

class TestUser:
    def setup_method(self, method):
        self.postgres = testing.postgresql.Postgresql(cache_initialized_db=True)
        self.db = psycopg2.connect(**self.postgres.dsn())

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        self.db.close()

    def test_get_users(self):
        res = client.get("/users")
        assert res.status_code == 200
        assert res.headers["content-type"] == "application/json"
```

my question is how to make my tests and cruds send queries to the test database, not the development database.

where is the link that I should add here?

Edit: this is the code I use for connection with database, I am not using a dependency for it :

```py
while True:
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            database=settings.database,
            user=settings.user,
            port=settings.port,
            password=settings.password,
            cursor_factory=RealDictCursor,
        )
        cr = conn.cursor()
        console.print(
            "[green bold]SUCCESS[/]:    Connection To Database Established successfuly"
        )
        break
    except psycopg2.OperationalError:
        console.print(
            "[red bold]FAILED[/]:    Connection To Database Failed , Trying Again"
        )
        time.sleep(2)
```

Edit2: this is the settings segment :

```py
load_dotenv()


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    database: str
    user: str
    port: int
    password: str
    expiray: int
    algorithm: str
    secret_key: str


settings = Settings()
```

Comment: This would depend on how you're using the database _in your FastAPI app_. FastAPI has `dependency_overrides` to replace a dependency when testing: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/

Comment: but this override method is used to override the dependency of the orm , when using none orm i don't have a dependency to override!

Comment: How are you retrieving the current database connection in your FastAPI application? Do you have a global variable? And in that case; any reason why you can't use a dependency to return the current connection to use, which you can then override in your tests? Dependencies aren't just useful for ORMs (that would be the session, usually). Also, from your question it sounds like you're using an ORM that is named "None", not that you aren't using a ORM. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: i edited the post and added the code i am using for connection with database take a look at it

Comment: Kareem, can you show where and how the `settings` object is created? That's probably where you'll want to dynamically determine the attributes based on whether you're in "testing" vs. "dev"

Comment: @Zev Averbach
I added the settings segment

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use the test database rather than the development database you should create the testing database and let the backend application be able to find the testing database and use it.

Comment: and how to make my backend do that, i am not using a dependency or what so ever.

Comment: For me, I had written the script which used to change the environment config of the .env, each time the project kick start it will load the .env file and determine whether use develop DB or production DB or not

Answer (score 0):

Kareem, I suggest you create your `Settings` instance from one or another `.env` file, based on an `ENVIRONMENT` variable:

```py
import os
import sys

import pydantic


class Settings(pydantic.BaseSettings):
    database: str
    user: str
    port: int
    password: str
    expiray: int
    algorithm: str
    secret_key: str


try:
    ENVIRONMENT = os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']
except KeyError:
    print('make sure to set an "ENVIRONMENT" env var')
    sys.exit()

    
settings = Settings(_env_file=f'{ENVIRONMENT}.env', _env_file_encoding='utf-8')
```

This way, if you want to work with the testing database, you can do `$ export ENVIRONMENT=test` and it will load the settings from a file called `test.env`.

Does that make sense? [Here are the docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/settings/#dotenv-env-support) for `pydantic`'s `dotenv` support for `BaseSettings` subclasses.

As an aside, since you're interested in doing as much as you can without the use of an ORM and perhaps other dependencies, you really don't need `pydantic` for your purposes: You could simply change the above to something like:

```py
import os
import sys
import types

import dotenv


try:
    ENVIRONMENT = os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']
except KeyError:
    print('make sure to set an "ENVIRONMENT" env var')
    sys.exit()


db_settings_dict = dotenv.dotenv_values(f"{ENVIRONMENT}.env")

# to get dot notation as in your example
settings = types.SimpleNamespace(**db_settings_dict)
```

where `test.env` contains things like

```
database=hey.there.com:8768
user=kareem
...
```

Comment: wow, that is some handy trick there thanks, this works for switching between prebuilt databases but what if I want to create and drop a database for each request I make then I have to rely on dependencies or what? how would you approach this?

Comment: Kareem, that sounds like a separate question. Is this for unit testing? If so, you should have a look at pytest and its handy fixture decorator. Feel free to link to your separate question here and I'll have a crack at it. Otherwise, I can't think of a reason to create and destroy databases per request in production.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Script I was written to control the ENV variable from the .env file, before running the unicorn server you would load the .env file based on the ENV mode to determine what kinds of modes are working on then use conditions to set up the corresponding DB path and name.

```py
import os
import sys
from colored import fg
from os import environ, path
from dotenv import load_dotenv, set_key
import dotenv


def unknown(option, args=None):
    color = fg('red')
    if args:
        print(color + f'Unknown arguments: -{args}')
    else:
        print(color + f'Unknown option: -{option}')
    print("usage: python3 config.py [option] [arguments]")
    print("Try `python3 config.py --help for more information")
    color = fg('white')
    print(color)


def version():
    basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
    load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '.env'))
    color = fg('blue')
    print(color + '[VERSION]: ' + environ.get('VER'))
    color = fg('white')
    print(color)


def env():
    basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
    load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '.env'))
    color = fg('blue')
    print(color + '[ENV]: ' + environ.get('ENV'))
    color = fg('white')
    print(color)


def set_env(env):
    dotenv_file = dotenv.find_dotenv()

    basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
    load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '.env'))
    color = fg('blue')
    print(color + f"[Updating ENV] ... ... from {environ.get('ENV')} to {env}")
    os.environ["ENV"] = env
    set_key(dotenv_file, 'ENV', os.environ['ENV'])
    print("[Successfully Update the 'ENV' from .env]")
    color = fg('white')
    print(color)


def doc():
    color = fg('blue')
    print(color + "usage: python3 config.py [option] [arguments]")

    read_me = """
    -v                  : current project version
    -env                : current project environment
    -set ENV={env}      : set project env 'DEV' or 'PROD'
    """
    print(read_me)
    color = fg('white')
    print(color)


def action_handler(option, args):
    if option == '-set':
        args_list = args.split('=')
        if args_list[0] == 'ENV' and (args_list[1] == 'DEV' or args_list[1] == 'PROD'):
            set_env(args_list[1])
        else:
            unknown(option=option, args=args)
    else:
        unknown(option=option)


argvs = len(sys.argv)

if argvs == 1:
    doc()
elif argvs == 2:
    option = sys.argv[1]
    if option == '--help':
        doc()
    elif option == '-v':
        version()
    elif option == '-env':
        env()
    else:
        unknown(option)
elif argvs == 3:
    option, args = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
    action_handler(option, args)
else:
    pass
```